# Adjusting the left margin of glossaries

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature, nomencl

Alright, let's try this working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glsmcols}{2}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]}
\setglossary{mcolalttree}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Nomenclature}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abbreviations}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\newglossaryentry{pt}{name=$\sfrac{P_{T2}}{P_{T0}}$, description={Ratio of total pressure at AIP to freestream total pressure}}
\newglossaryentry{y+}{name=$y^{+}$, description={Dimensionless distance from wall boundaries}}
\newglossaryentry{d}{name=$D$, description={AIP diameter}}
\newglossaryentry{m2}{name=$M_2$, description={Mach number at AIP}}%
\newglossaryentry{pt2avg}{name=$P_{T2_{avg}}$, description={Average of 40 AIP Kulite\textsuperscript{\textregistered} total pressures}}%
\newglossaryentry{p2avg}{name=$P_{2_{avg}}$, description={Average of 8 AIP static tap pressures}}
\newglossaryentry{ds}{name=$\Delta s$, description={Distance measured between neighboring grid points}}
\newglossaryentry{dpcp}{name=DPCP, description={Circumferential distortion intensity}}
\newglossaryentry{dprp}{name=DPRP, description={Radial distortion intensity}}
\newglossaryentry{pav}{name=PAV, description={Average ring pressure}}
\newglossaryentry{pavlow}{name=PAVLOW, description={Average low pressure}}  \gls{pavlow}

\newacronym{aip}{AIP}{Aerodynamic Interface Plane}\gls{aip}
\newacronym{amr}{AMR}{Adaptive Mesh Refinement}
\newacronym{gcr}{GCR}{Generalized Conjugate Residual}

\glsaddall

\end{document}
```

Now I would like to adjust the margins on either side of the glossary so that both left and right margins are larger by about 3em.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: My question is related to whether something can be accomplished, not why something I've done doesn't work.  I don't have a working example.  I simply want to understand whether there is a method available to change the left margin for glossaries by itself as exists with the nomencl package.

Comment: Yes, it's possible -- but for the "how it's possible" it would be nice to have some small example document to start with.

Comment: There are [rather a lot of predefined styles](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/), and you can also define your own custom styles. As @samcarter has already commented, the answer to your question is simply yes, but how you implement it depends on the style.

Comment: \documentclass{article}

Comment: @user3394147 Where can we find the package `glossary-cols`? It's not on ctan https://www.ctan.org/search/?phrase=glossary-cols

Comment: The package is actually called glossary-mcols.  My autocorrect changed it in the original post.  I have since corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the entire glossary inside a list and adjust the list margins like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glsmcols}{2}
\setglossarystyle{mcolalttree}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{%
 \glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]
 \begin{list}{}%
 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{3em}\rightmargin\leftmargin}% margins
 \item\relax}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\end{list}}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Nomenclature}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abbreviations}


\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\newglossaryentry{pt}{name=$\frac{P_{T2}}{P_{T0}}$, description={Ratio of total pressure at AIP to freestream total pressure}}
\newglossaryentry{y+}{name=$y^{+}$, description={Dimensionless distance from wall boundaries}}
\newglossaryentry{d}{name=$D$, description={AIP diameter}}
\newglossaryentry{m2}{name=$M_2$, description={Mach number at AIP}}%
\newglossaryentry{pt2avg}{name=$P_{T2_{avg}}$, description={Average of 40 AIP Kulite\textsuperscript{\textregistered} total pressures}}%
\newglossaryentry{p2avg}{name=$P_{2_{avg}}$, description={Average of 8 AIP static tap pressures}}
\newglossaryentry{ds}{name=$\Delta s$, description={Distance measured between neighboring grid points}}
\newglossaryentry{dpcp}{name=DPCP, description={Circumferential distortion intensity}}
\newglossaryentry{dprp}{name=DPRP, description={Radial distortion intensity}}
\newglossaryentry{pav}{name=PAV, description={Average ring pressure}}
\newglossaryentry{pavlow}{name=PAVLOW, description={Average low pressure}}  \gls{pavlow}

\newacronym{aip}{AIP}{Aerodynamic Interface Plane}\gls{aip}
\newacronym{amr}{AMR}{Adaptive Mesh Refinement}
\newacronym{gcr}{GCR}{Generalized Conjugate Residual}

\glsaddall

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

The gap between columns can be adjusted by changing `\columnsep`.

Unrelated, but [I recommend you move your definitions to the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Comment: I get an error when trying to reproduce this: LaTeX Error:  \begin{document} ended by \end{list}.

Comment: @user3394147 The example code in this answer works fine for me. Did you copy and paste it completely? (Ignore the lipsum package. That crept in by accident. I'll remove it.) Check also the package versions to make sure they're up to date.